# Is there faster base-2 conversion than Convert.ToString(byte,2)?

Tags: .net, binary, converters, radix

Is there a faster way to do base-2 conversion than using `Convert.ToString(byte,2)`

I will be running this in a loop:

```
Function varintbinaryToint(b() As Byte) As Integer
    Const b127 As Byte = 127
    Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder

    For i = b.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        sb.AppendFormat(Convert.ToString(b(i) And b127, 2).PadLeft(7, "0"c))
    Next

    Return Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString, 2)

    --to binary      1100 0100  ‬ ‭0001 0110‬
    --remove msb     ‭ 100 0100  ‬ ‭ 001 0110‬
    --reverse         001 0110‬    100 0100
    --join           10110‬1000100
    --bin 2 int      2884
End Function
```

Comment: Precompute an array.

Comment: @TomBlodget Please i dot follow?

Comment: This is a suggestion rather than an answer. Move the code out of the loop to create an array that can indexed faster than running the code each pass. `Private Shared SevenBitZeroPaddedBinary = Enumerable.Range(0,128).Select(Function(i) Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(7,"0"c)).ToArray()` Then you can `sb.Append(SevenBitZeroPaddedBinary(b(i) And b127))`. [Sorry for the rewrites of this comment but it took me a few to get it right.]

Comment: @tom-blodget I can't seem to make you code suggestion work for my given example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at the source for Convert.ToString(byte,int)

It makes a call to a Native implementation, so i guess it's as fast as we can have:

```
ParseNumbers.IntToString((int)value, toBase, -1, ' ', ParseNumbers.PrintAsI1)
```

The source code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/parsenumbers.cs,9d6624da44b02e1f

States:

> ** Class:  ParseNumbers
>
> ** Purpose: Methods for Parsing numbers and Strings.
>
> ** All methods are implemented in native.

Answer (score 0):

By moving the code out of the loop to create an array that can be indexed faster than running the code each pass, you might save time during each function call. (Obviously, this isn't a faster base-2 conversion because it uses the same code for the conversion.)

```
Private Shared SevenBitZeroPaddedBinary = Enumerable.Range(0,128) _
    .Select(Function(i) Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(7,"0"c)) _
    .ToArray() 

Function varintbinaryToint(b() As Byte) As Integer
    Const b127 As Byte = 127
    Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder

    For i = b.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        sb.Append(SevenBitZeroPaddedBinary(b(i) And b127))
    Next

    Return Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString, 2)

    '--to binary      1100 0100  ‬ ‭0001 0110‬
    '--remove msb     ‭ 100 0100  ‬ ‭ 001 0110‬
    '--reverse         001 0110‬    100 0100
    '--join           10110‬1000100
    '--bin 2 int      2884
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you've misdiagnosed the bottleneck. You could possibly do the entire manipulation without strings.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer along that line, i'm not very savy at direct byte manipulation and bit shifting

Comment: That's worthy of a separate, complete question. (What is `b() As Byte`? We can only tell that you expect it have at least one element.) Regarding bit shifting, thankfully Visual Basic (fka Visual Basic .NET) is not Visual Basic (of the VB6 era).

Comment: :) I dont follow your comment on vb6 and vb.net